# Azure DSC on windows server with added data disk

Tags: azure, dsc

I am running a DSC script on a SQL server to create databases I am trying to specify that they need to go to the F:\ drive but the drive doesn't exist. If I create the VM without mentioning the F:\ drive it appears.

I tried doing a DO While to wait for the drive to get provisioned but the DSC script eventually times out. It appears Azure Creates the data disk after the DSC script is ran. Is there a way to change the order? If not, what would I do to solve this problem?

Update: I also verified that the ARM template says the DSC extension depends on the SQL VM. I would think that would mean the DSC extension wouldn't deploy until the VM is done provisioning.

Comment: At the end of the day, my workaround was to add a second extension ahead of the SQL provisioning script.  This added enough time to allow the script to run successfully. I'm not pleased with this solution, but it worked.